# in theory: would this be possible: SQL query for efficient use of build parts

Tags: sql, theory

I have a couple of tables, which I have simplified to the extreme for the purpose of this example.

**Table 1, 'Units'**

```
ID    UnitName    PartNumber
1     UnitX       1
2     UnitX       1
3     UnitX       2
4     UnitX       3
5     UnitX       3
6     UnitY       1
7     UnitY       2
8     UnitY       3
```

**Table 2, 'Parts'**

```
ID    PartName    Quantity
1     Screw       2
2     Wire        1
3     Ducttape    1
```

I would like to query on these tables which of these units would be Possible to build, AND if so, which one could be built first ideally to make efficient use of these parts.

Now the question is: can this be done using SQL, or is a background application required/more efficient?

So in this example, it is easy, because only one unit (unit Y) can be built.. But I guess you get the idea. (I'm not looking for a shake and bake answer, just your thoughts on this.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you present it, it is efficient to use sql. As you described PartNumber column of table Units is a foreign key on ID column of Parts table, so a simple outer join or selecting units that the PartNumber are "NOT IN" the Parts table would give you the units that can not be build.

However if your db schema consists of many non normalised tables, or is very complex without indexes, other "bad" things etc 
it could be examined whether specific application code is faster. But i really doubt it for the particular case, the query seems trivial.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts on this. <br> that would indeed be easy for flat checking which ones could be built at a point in time. <br> however: It could be that multiple 'units' can be made, only some use more parts. I'd need a way to subtract the number of leftover parts to determine what is left to build with. (and thus what units would be best to start with using the inventory to the fullest (e.g. which method leaves the least leftover parts))

Comment: That needs application logic. Because among others, you need the flexibility of modifying the criteria on which you determine that the inventory is used to the fullest. For example you start by checking how you could build the most parts, but later on you add a priority/significance to parts and you want to change that logic or some parts may require others to be build first etc. In any case you should break things down and focus on implementing each part of your system in the most efficient way e.g. using only app logic, sql or mixture.